# ¿Hay acento en "aniversario"?

Tags: ortografía, acentuación

Acabo de buscar un imagen de un logo de ["Feliz Aniversario" en Google](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1600&bih=752&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=%C2%A1Feliz%20aniversario!%20logo&oq=%C2%A1Feliz%20aniversario!%20logo), y muchas de las respuestas tienen un acento en la segunda 'a': **aniversário*.  Pero, según el [DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2ieoSuF), no hay tal acento.

¿Cuál es correcta?

---

I just now searched for a ["Happy Anniversary" logo image on Google](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1600&bih=752&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=%C2%A1Feliz%20aniversario!%20logo&oq=%C2%A1Feliz%20aniversario!%20logo), and most of the hits have an accent on the second 'a': *aniversário*.  But, according to the [RAE Spanish Dictionary](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2ieoSuF), there isn't such an accent.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo correcto es, como ves en la entrada del DLE, **sin acento**.

`Aniversario` es una palabra llana (a-ni-ver-**sa**-rio). Las palabras llanas solo llevan tilde si **no** terminan en vocal, ni en `n`, ni en `s`. Dado que  `aniversario` termina en vocal, con el diptongo `io`, esta palabra no lleva tilde.

¿Por qué entonces en algunas de esas imágenes aparece con acento de la segunda "a" (*aniversário*)? Pues porque es otro idioma, no español. En este caso creo que es **portugés**.

- Wordreference: [aniversário](http://www.wordreference.com/ptes/anivers%C3%A1rio)
- Linguee: [aniversario-aniverário](http://www.linguee.es/espanol-portugues/traduccion/feliz+aniversario.html)

Por la "magia" del buscador de Google, los "caracteres" raros como vocales acentuadas o la "ñ" a veces son modificadas, filtradas o ignoradas en la búsqueda o los resultados (buscar "Espana" y "España" puede producir los mismos resultados por ejemplo).

Comment: Así es, las reglas de acentuación en portugués son diferentes, y vocal débil seguido por vocal fuerte al final de una palabra se considera como hiato y no diptongo a menos que haya un tilde en otro sitio (y aún así, algunos las pronunciarán como diptongo o hiato átono sin distinción)

Answer (score 0):

Las respuestas con acento están en portugués. Google no diferencia palabras por sus acentos, entonces estás recibiendo resultados mixtos. No hay acento en `Feliz Aniversario`.